# Linking "itms-apps://" link to redeem gifted app within html email

Tags: html, ios

HTML novice here stumbling around with modifying some email code that put together using some online generators and such. I am trying to send an email to customers with an embedded link that will automatically open the iOS app store "redeem" button for an app that I have gifted them.

The link to accomplish this for a given "gifted app" is as follows:

```
itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=PROMOCODEHERE?mt=8
```

This link works fine when clicked from iMessage, apple Notes, etc on iPhone (I.e., opens the app store and just has a redeem button, thus allowing the person to directly install the app to their phone). It would also work just fine if you remove the `itms-apps://` portion and the user defaults to Safari browser - the issue I'm trying to avoid is if they use a non-default browser (Chrome, etc) so that the link goes direct to app store.

Within the email, I'm using the following (the itms-apps:// link is technically called from a variable, but I've tried it with and without variable to no success). The email sends and the button this link is in just does nothing on iPhone, isn't tappable etc.

```
<a href="itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=PROMOCODEHERE?mt=8" class="es-button" target="_blank">TAP FROM iOS TO INSTALL</a>
```

So far, as mentioned I've tried

1. Removing the variable which calls in the promo code app store link
2. Using a [URL encoder](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to make sure special/reserved characters aren't an issue (result looks like the following)

```
<a href="itms-apps%3A%2F%2Fbuy.itunes.apple.com%2FWebObjects%2FMZFinance.woa%2Fwa%2FfreeProductCodeWizard%3Fcode%3D+76AHA94HNMH6%3Fmt%3D8" class="es-button" target="_blank">TAP FROM iOS TO INSTALL</a>
```

... but these options aren't working. Would love any thoughts as to how to approach this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the button this link is in" What does _that_ mean? A link and a button are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your Info.plist

[image]

Comment: I stretched the details a little bit - the specific issue pertains to a different app that I do not own (we're giving away copies of apps as part of a hype generator of sorts). I won't be able to add to info.plist. It's weird to me that this link works in other places in iOS but not within the HTML of an email, so clearly I'm missing something about how this all works. Is there no way to make it work within HTML then?